# Bootstrap 4 Collapse - Elements that are collapsed stay open when opening another accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I don't find this in the documentation, but how can I force the element to stay open when another one is opened. Example:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

```
<div id="exampleAccordion" data-children=".item">
   <div class="item">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#exampleAccordion" href="#exampleAccordion1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="exampleAccordion1">
  Toggle item
      </a>
      <div id="exampleAccordion1" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel">
        <p class="mb-3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pretium lorem non vestibulum scelerisque. Proin a vestibulum sem, eget tristique massa. Aliquam lacinia rhoncus nibh quis ornare.
        </p>
      </div>
   </div>


<div class="item">
   <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#exampleAccordion" href="#exampleAccordion2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="exampleAccordion2">
  Toggle item 2
   </a>
   <div id="exampleAccordion2" class="collapse" role="tabpanel">
      <p class="mb-3">
    Donec at ipsum dignissim, rutrum turpis scelerisque, tristique lectus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus nec dui turpis. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#multiple-targets

Comment: I don't get it sorry. Take the example of https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example. I don't see the difference only that they used the class "multi-collapse", but this didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this, it will work,

HTML
-----
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion-option">
    <h3 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-accordion active" accordion-id="#accordion"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
         content 1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
          content 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
----
body {
  color: #6a6c6f;
  background-color: #f1f3f6;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e4e5e7;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  float: right;
  transition: transform .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s linear;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\2212";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\002b";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.accordion-option {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.accordion-option .title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6a6c6f;
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion:before {
  content: "Expand All";
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion.active:before {
  content: "Collapse All";
}

Javascript:
-----------
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".toggle-accordion").on("click", function() {
    var accordionId = $(this).attr("accordion-id"),
      numPanelOpen = $(accordionId + ' .collapse.in').length;

    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    if (numPanelOpen == 0) {
      openAllPanels(accordionId);
    } else {
      closeAllPanels(accordionId);
    }
  })

  openAllPanels = function(aId) {
    console.log("setAllPanelOpen");
    $(aId + ' .panel-collapse:not(".in")').collapse('show');
  }
  closeAllPanels = function(aId) {
    console.log("setAllPanelclose");
    $(aId + ' .panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
  }

});
```